# Run Jenkins Azure ACI Docker Agents on Same Vnet as Host

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins

### Question

How do I specify what virtual-network (vnet) or subnet an Azure Docker Instances (ACI) runs on with the [Azure Container Agents](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Azure+Container+Agents+Plugin) Plugin for Jenkins?

### Assumptions

In order to get lots of data transferred between two machines in Azure, those machines ought to be in the same vnet.

It is possible to get ACI's to run within a subnet of a vnet to get this fast communication.

### Background

I'm running an Azure VM with Jenkins on it. This same VM also has Nexus installed on it for proxying/caching 3rd party dependencies. I'm running my builds on Docker Containers that are dynamically created as needed and destroyed afterwards for cost savings. This ACI creation/destruction introduces a problem in that the local .m2 cache does not survive one build to the next. Nexus is being used to fix this problem by facilitating fast access to 3rd party dependencies.

But for Nexus to really solve this problem, it seems as if the ACI's need to be in the same vnet as Nexus. I'd also like the advantage of not needing to open up ports to the world, but can pass data around within the vnet without having to open ports from that vnet to the internet.

My problem is that I seem to have no control over which vnet or subnet the ACI's run on with the plugin I'm using (Azure Container Agents Plugin).

I've found instructions on how to specify the subnet on an ACI in general ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet)), but that doesn't help me as I need a solution that works with the Jenkins Plugin I'm using.

But perhaps this plugin will not work for my purposes and I need to abandon it for another approach. If so, suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you need to use the AKS for your Jenkins, and use the virtual nodes with ACI. So there are in the vnet as the AKS nodes.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Azure Container Agents Plugin for Jenkins currently doesn't support specifying what virtual network (vnet) an ACI runs on. 
I think you should raise an issue [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/azure-container-agents-plugin/issues) to see if you get better response.

And yes, you may need to abandon this approach of using ACI Jenkins agents and as a workaround (for now) should go with VM's as Jenkins agents 
or run the Jenkins jobs on Jenkins master itself so that local .m2 cache would survive one build to the next.

Related References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-jenkins

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-jenkins?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fjenkins%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json

Hope this helps!!